# Unable to connect to my UxPlay on Airplay when trying to mirror iphone screen to linux machine

Tags: ios, linux

I am trying to use UxPlay to mirror my iphone screen onto my linux machine.

I have followed the guide to install UxPlay, and when I run it in my temrinal I get:

```
using system MAC address 08:92:...
Initialized server socket(s)
```

And when I open the mirror screen on my iPhone, I do see the option to conenct to my UxPlay, however when I click on 'connect', I get the error:

```
Unable to connect to "UxPlay@patrick-Ip".
```

Any ideas what I could try to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check if you have a firewall active.
   if so, open 3 tcp and 3 udp ports and use then with the -p ....
   option, or stop the firewall
2. readthe README at the uxplay site.